# uszipcode Windows command prompt: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, cmd

I have been working with the module uszipcode without problem in anaconda, but 
when moving to Windows command prompt, I get an error failing the DLL load.
I am using python3 in Windows 10

```
>>> uszipcode.__version__
'0.2.2'

>>> sys.version
'3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]'

>>> import uszipcode
>>> uszipcode.SearchEngine()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 334, in dbapi
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py", line 82, in __init__
    engine = connect_to_simple_zipcode_db()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\db.py", line 49, in connect_to_simple_zipcode_db
    return engine_creator.create_sqlite(path=simple_db_file_path.abspath)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\pkg\sqlalchemy_mate\engine_creator.py", line 51, in create_sqlite
    return create_engine(_create_sqlite(path), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 425, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 81, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 339, in dbapi
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 337, in dbapi
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite  # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed pysqlite2 in your Anaconda environment?

Comment: No, but from jupyter notebooks, spyder... it works. Anyway, I am no able to install pysqlite2, pysqlite neither sqlite3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created an environment with python 3.6 and the issue has been solved.